# How do I prevent a HTML page from wrapping between individual words without preventing it from wrapping the line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a page to display something like this, when there's space for it:

> **Name:** Peter Petersen

And then if the name is too long for the page, it should NOT break between words, but move the entire line down, a la:

> **Name:**
>
> Peter Petersen

I'm currently using two separate paragraphs for the title and the value, with the following CSS:

```
.title {
   float:left;
   width: 40%;
}
.value {
   width: 60%
}
```

If I run it like that, it shows:

> **Name:** Peter
>
> Petersen

Which is not what I want. I tried adding `white-space: nowrap` to the value, but then the text never wraps down to the line below, but just continues off the edge of the screen. 
`word-break: keep-all;` is not what I'm looking for either, since that just keeps words together.

Every other question on this I've been able to find has just been about disabling word-breaking, without caring that the line as a whole never breaks.

Comment: In some answers I see the usage of 'white-space: nowrap', beware that with longer names they will be cut off on smaller screens. If the content really doesn't fit any more, the surname should just wrap to a new line. Accessible content should always be the highest priority. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex box will do the trick ;)

HTML:

```
<div class="a">
  <span>name:</span>
  <span class="name">Peter Peterson</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.name {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y06d8vu4/

Answer (score 0):

html code:

```
 <div class = "wrap">
        <span>Name: </span>
        <span>Peter Peterson</span>
 </div>
```

css code :

```
.wrap {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap span:first-child {
     margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The words you *don't* want to break should be in their own element with `white-space: nowrap`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

span:nth-of-type(1) {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

span:nth-of-type(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom:1em;  
}

.wrapper.narrow {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Name:</span>
  <span>Peter Peterson</span>
</div>

<div class="wrapper narrow">
  <span>Name:</span>
  <span>Peter Peterson</span>
</div>
```